# Target Encoding : Fill NaN generated in expanding mean encoded values

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, feature-engineering

I am working on multi-class classification problem having five classes in the target column. I have generated features for categorical variables using expanding mean encoding(Target encoding). The method is based on encoding categorical variable values with mean of target variable per value.

This also results in some NaN values like in 'Transaction-Type_mean_target' column.

1. What is the best way to fill these NaN values? Should I fill
   these with the column mean.
2. How do I generate mean encoding for my test data as the
   target/Dependent variable 'Complaint-Status' is not present?

Input data :

[image]

Generating mean encoding :

```
def add_feat_mean_encoding(col_list):
    """
        Expanding mean encoding 
    """
    for i in col_list:
        cumsum = train.groupby(i)['Complaint-Status'].cumsum() - train['Complaint-Status']
        cumcnt = train.groupby(i).cumcount()
        train[i+'_mean_target'] = cumsum/cumcnt

cat_var = ['Transaction-Type','Complaint-reason','Company-response','Consumer-disputes']
add_feat_mean_encoding(cat_var)
```

Comment: Hallo, just to understand: Which among your features are categorical and which are scalar? CmpantStatus is a scalar or categorical (boolean perhaps, 0/1) ?

Answer (score 1):

If your features are categorical, imputing with mean does not make sense, at least it means that you create a new value for Nans. is that what you want ?

In order  to answer your questions :

1. For categorical features, you may try different ways. You may start with `SimpleImputer` of scikit (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html)), try for example :

```py
FILL_VALUE=100
imp_1 = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
imp_2 = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant', fille_value=FILL_VALUE)
```

2. Please provide information on your testset : which are the features ? If you do not have the feature `Complaint-Status` in the testset, there are two ways :

   - You can predict the feature `Complaint-Status`, for the test set, using the training set (and the feature you wish to predict, `Complaint-Status`, as Y). Try different classifiers and choose the one which provides the best result.
   - You can also use a 2 dimension Y, with your actual Y + `Complaint-Status`.